# Trying to compile LinuxSamplers via g++

Tags: linux, compilation, g++, bison, cflags

im quiet new to the compiling stuff. However, i tried to compile the LinuxSampler starting with libgig. I downloaded the Repositories, adjusted the "rules" (./config) file and so on, just as described there https://linuxsampler.org/debian.html . Well, it worked good enough that all .deb files were created and installed (at least i could pass the commands without getting error messages). Then i tried the same steps as i did for libgig package with linuxsampler packages, but i cannot create does .deb files.
I installed bison-2.3, any lib that caused any dependency problems and *g++, debhelper, pkg-config, automake, autoconf, libtool, fakeroot*.
The problem is, when i run *dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b* I get this.:

```
debian/rules build
dh_testdir

if [ -e Makefile.svn ] ; then \
    /usr/bin/make -f Makefile.svn; \
fi
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/name/SoundSachen/linuxsampler'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'default'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/name/SoundSachen/linuxsampler'
chmod a+x configure
CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -mss3 -fvectorize -pipe -m32" ./configure  --prefix=/usr --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in '/home/name/SoundSachen/linuxsampler':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See config.log' for more details
make: *** [debian/rules:26: configure-stamp] Error 77
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2`
```

This the file with the ./config and CFLAGS line:

```html
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-
# Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
# This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
# As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
# dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
# This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

CFLAGS = -Wall -g

ifneq (,$(findstring noopt,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)))
    CFLAGS += -O0
else
    CFLAGS += -O2
endif

configure: configure-stamp
configure-stamp:
    dh_testdir
    # Add here commands to configure the package.
    if [ -e Makefile.svn ] ; then \
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.svn; \
    fi
    chmod a+x configure
    CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -mss3 -fvectorize -pipe -m32" ./configure  --prefix=/usr --mandir=\$${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\$${prefix}/share/info
    touch configure-stamp


build: build-stamp

build-stamp: configure-stamp
    dh_testdir

    # Add here commands to compile the package.
    $(MAKE)
    #   docbook-to-man debian/linuxsampler.sgml > linuxsampler.1

    #   $(MAKE)

    # generate Doxygen API documentation
    $(MAKE) docs

    touch build-stamp

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp

    if [ -e Makefile.svn ] ; then \
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.svn; \
    fi;
    # Add here commands to clean up after the build process.
    chmod a+x configure
    ./configure  --prefix=/usr --mandir=\$${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\$${prefix}/share/info

    -$(MAKE) distclean

    dh_clean

install: build
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_clean -k
    dh_installdirs

    # Add here commands to install the package into debian/tmp.
    $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/tmp
    mkdir -p debian/tmp/etc/ld.so.conf.d
    echo /usr/lib/linuxsampler > debian/tmp/etc/ld.so.conf.d/linuxsampler.conf


# Build architecture-independent files here.
binary-indep: build install
# We have nothing to do by default.

# Build architecture-dependent files here.
binary-arch: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_install -a --list-missing
    dh_installchangelogs -a ChangeLog
    dh_installdocs -a
    dh_installexamples
#   dh_install
#   dh_installmenu
#   dh_installdebconf
#   dh_installlogrotate
#   dh_installemacsen
#   dh_installpam
#   dh_installmime
#   dh_installinit
#   dh_installcron
#   dh_installinfo
    dh_installman man/linuxsampler.1
    dh_link
#   dh_strip
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
#   dh_perl
#   dh_python
    dh_makeshlibs -pliblinuxsampler
    dh_installdeb -a
    dh_shlibdeps # -L linuxsampler -l debian/linuxsampler/usr/lib/linuxsampler
    dh_shlibdeps -pliblinuxsampler
    dh_gencontrol -a
    dh_md5sums -a
    dh_builddeb -a

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install configure
```

`Added conf.log below

Please help! Thanks:)

```html
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by linuxsampler configure 2.2.0.svn7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = okdude-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.4.0-91-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/bin/m4
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3119: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3187: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3198: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3253: result: yes
configure:3402: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3441: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3448: checking for gawk
configure:3478: result: no
configure:3448: checking for mawk
configure:3464: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:3475: result: mawk
configure:3486: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3508: result: yes
configure:3537: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3554: result: yes
configure:3728: checking for gcc
configure:3744: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3755: result: gcc
configure:3984: checking for C compiler version
configure:3993: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4004: $? = 0
configure:3993: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 
configure:4004: $? = 0
configure:3993: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4004: $? = 1
configure:3993: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4004: $? = 1
configure:4024: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4046: gcc -O2 -march=native -mss3 -fvectorize -pipe -m32   conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mss3'; did you mean '-msse'?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fvectorize'
configure:4050: $? = 1
configure:4088: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "linuxsampler"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "linuxsampler"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.2.0.svn7"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "linuxsampler 2.2.0.svn7"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define LSCP_RELEASE_MAJOR 1
| #define LSCP_RELEASE_MINOR 7
| #define PACKAGE "linuxsampler"
| #define VERSION "2.2.0.svn7"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4093: error: in `/home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler':
configure:4095: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-O2 -march=native -mss3 -fvectorize -pipe -m32'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_GIG_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GIG_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GIG_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GIG_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_JACK_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_JACK_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_JACK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_JACK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_LV2_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LV2_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LV2_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LV2_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_SNDFILE_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SNDFILE_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SNDFILE_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_SNDFILE_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_SQLITE3_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SQLITE3_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SQLITE3_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_SQLITE3_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler/missing aclocal-1.16'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
ARTS_CFLAGS=''
ARTS_CONFIG=''
ARTS_LIBS=''
AS=''
ASIOSDK_BASEDIR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler/missing automake-1.16'
AWK='mawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-O2 -march=native -mss3 -fvectorize -pipe -m32'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CROSS_COMPILING_FALSE=''
CROSS_COMPILING_TRUE=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXX_CPU_SWITCH=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DEVELOPER_EXTRAS_DIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GIG_CFLAGS=''
GIG_LIBS=''
GREP=''
HAVE_ALSA_FALSE=''
HAVE_ALSA_TRUE=''
HAVE_ARTS_FALSE=''
HAVE_ARTS_TRUE=''
HAVE_ASIO_FALSE=''
HAVE_ASIO_TRUE=''
HAVE_AUFLAGS_FALSE=''
HAVE_AUFLAGS_TRUE=''
HAVE_AU_FALSE=''
HAVE_AU_TRUE=''
HAVE_COREAUDIO_FALSE=''
HAVE_COREAUDIO_TRUE=''
HAVE_COREMIDI_FALSE=''
HAVE_COREMIDI_TRUE=''
HAVE_CXX14=''
HAVE_DSSI_FALSE=''
HAVE_DSSI_TRUE=''
HAVE_JACK_FALSE=''
HAVE_JACK_MIDI_FALSE=''
HAVE_JACK_MIDI_TRUE=''
HAVE_JACK_TRUE=''
HAVE_LV2_FALSE=''
HAVE_LV2_TRUE=''
HAVE_MIDISHARE_FALSE=''
HAVE_MIDISHARE_TRUE=''
HAVE_MME_MIDI_FALSE=''
HAVE_MME_MIDI_TRUE=''
HAVE_SF2_FALSE=''
HAVE_SF2_TRUE=''
HAVE_SQLITE3_FALSE=''
HAVE_SQLITE3_TRUE=''
HAVE_VST_FALSE=''
HAVE_VST_TRUE=''
HAVE_WINDOWS_FALSE=''
HAVE_WINDOWS_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
JACK_CFLAGS=''
JACK_LIBS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIB_EXT=''
LINUX_FALSE=''
LINUX_TRUE=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
LV2_CFLAGS=''
LV2_LIBS=''
MAC_FALSE=''
MAC_PLUGIN_INSTALL_DIR=''
MAC_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='linuxsampler'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='linuxsampler'
PACKAGE_STRING='linuxsampler 2.2.0.svn7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='linuxsampler'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.2.0.svn7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHARED_VERSION_INFO='6:0:0'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIB_VERSION_ARG=''
SNDFILE_CFLAGS=''
SNDFILE_LIBS=''
SQLITE3_CFLAGS=''
SQLITE3_LIBS=''
STRIP=''
VERSION='2.2.0.svn7'
VSTSDK_DIR=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
acx_pthread_config=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
config_asiosdk_dir=''
config_default_instruments_db_file=''
config_plugin_dir=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/share/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/okdude/SoundSachen/linuxsampler/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/share/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "linuxsampler"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "linuxsampler"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.2.0.svn7"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "linuxsampler 2.2.0.svn7"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define LSCP_RELEASE_MAJOR 1
#define LSCP_RELEASE_MINOR 7
#define PACKAGE "linuxsampler"
#define VERSION "2.2.0.svn7"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mss3'; did you mean '-msse'?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fvectorize'` and `CFLAGS="-O2 -march=native -mss3 -fvectorize -pipe -m32"` - remove the unknown flags. Do you know where they come from? From the readme that you linked, it llooks like you should manually edit the line. Just do `CFLAGS="-march=native -O2"` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks,but that doesnt help. Yes i put the CFLAGS  manually ithere. I think there is a problem in the build section from the "rules" file, which i did not change. However, it is not building the linuxsampler.deb files it should create. Or this "checking whether the C compiler works... no" maybe?

Comment: How do i close this question if i solved it but dont know how?